# Como sacar el .html de un link en mi pagina web

Tags: html5, web, diseño

Buenas. Tengo una simple consulta. Mi duda es la siguiente, este es el link de mi pagina web (ejemplo)

> https://ejemplo.com/contacto**.html**

Entonces quiero hacer que el link sea de esta forma:

> https://ejemplo.com/contacto

¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Te doy dos sugerencias (sin ningún orden de importancia particular): **a).-** Creas en tu sitio una carpeta *contacto* y dentro de la misma un archivo *index* (o cualquier nombre -más su extensión claro está- de los predeterminados en tu hosting) **b).-** Dependiendo el lenguaje en que desarrollas tu sitio busca como hacerlo en *patrón* **MVC**.

Answer (score 3):

Las opciones que te da Roberto en el comentario son validas, aunque no recomendadas o que pueden ser mas dificiles, pero hay una manera mas simple de hacerlo y es a traves del archivo **.htaccess**

Este archivo se encuentra en la raiz publica de tu hosting, si no hay uno puedes crearlo y escribir el siguiente codigo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Esto si solo trabajas con extensiones .html, si trabajas con .php u otras deberas agregar nuevas lineas para las extensiones correspondientes.

Si quieres que tu URL termine en barra `\` entonces en lugar del codigo anterior necesitas agregar el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Dejo el link fuente aunque [esta en ingles](http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)